# How can I mount this hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata

I pulled this hard drive out of an old HP laptop. I thought I could mount it because the label on the hard drive says it's a SATA:

[image]

Does anyone recognize what type of SATA interface is on this hard drive?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an adapter to me. Unscrew and remove it to expose the standard SATA connectors.

Comment: I thought so too at first, until i saw that both sides of the "adapter" don't have screws. The only other conclusion I drew was that it was soldered on, but I dismissed it as outlandish.

Comment: It has to be an adapter. It extends beyond the edge of the normal drive, and the label on the drive shows normal SATA connectors.

Comment: I agree - @TheRabbitMage, can you get a photo of the other side of the connector?  What is that metal plate that seems to be at a weird angle?

Comment: The drive is (visibly) still sitting in an additional casing that needs to be removed from the drive (which the black adapter is probably attached to). You can see it running up the sides of the drive in the pictures (thin aluminum). It's probably screwed into the drive on the sides, but perhaps from the bottom.

Comment: Nevermind. It is an adapter. I'm surprised I didn't catch it sooner. I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for the help.

[Other side of the connecter](http://i.imgur.com/IcdDk.jpg)

Comment: Yeah looks like it just slides off...